# Basic Authentication Angular2 (Not CORS)

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, typescript, http

I am currently trying to call a `jersey` REST API that I have running locally on `localhost:8080` through Angular 4 using `HttpClient`.

My Code:
```

```
ngOnInit() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'));
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/mycall?myparam=myvalue', {headers: headers}).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

```

When I make this call I get a `401` error saying that I am `Unauthorized`. However, when I run this through postman it goes through just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

**NOTE**: this is not a CORS issue, I am currently allowing CORS through an extension on firefox

Comment: Did you debug on the server and see why?

Comment: No messages on the server @epascarello

Comment: Use you browser dev tools. Go under Network tab and see what are the headers that ur api is really sending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpHeaders are immutable, so you need to do something like that

```
ngOnInit() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'))
    .append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/mycall?myparam=myvalue', {headers: headers}).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Actually you should not need the Content-type here for a GET request

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. I had no idea that HttpHeaders is immutable @David

Comment: Do you know of any way to not provide the request with the username and password, and let the browser trigger the login? @David

Comment: @M. Barbieri I don't think it's possible with ajax calls

Comment: You mean its not possible with the Angular HttpClient, because its definitely possible with ajax, all you have to do is leave the authentication out @David

Comment: @M. Barbieri I actually though it was not possible with ajax itself

Comment: it's definitely possible, I'm not sure if its recommended, but I guess topic for another question :) @David

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you haven't passed in your custom request headers to `HttpClient`, which is causing the unauthorised error.

Please try something like this.

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'));
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/mycall?myparam=myvalue', options ).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

You can simply pass in your `RequestOptions` to `http.get` as it does accept headers as an optional parameter. Please check following link for more details on the usage.

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get

Also, remember to import `RequestOptions` as well.

Comment: sorry I updated the question, so that is how I originally had it @woodykiddy

Comment: Also, please note that `RequestOptions` is deprecated @woodykiddy

Comment: @M.Barbieri you obviously could use the anonymous object instead of instantiating `RequestOptions` object, like `const options = {headers: headers}`, but don't think it'd matter though if you still getting 401 error. Have you checked the `btoa()` actually returns the correct value?